# BAT file for mstsc

Tags: batch-file, mstsc

i need to login to multiple windows servers. can anyone post me a Windows bat file sample for remote login instead of invoking mstsc and typing user id and password?

Answer (score 0):

Did you even attempt to look for an answer before asking the question?  I already know the answer to my question.

I did a search on google for *mstsc command line options*

and came up with [Use command line parameters with Remote Desktop Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mstsc)

Comment: sorry, i got the answer from http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Configuring-Windows-Remote-Desktop-command-line.html after i posted this qn.. thanks

Comment: updated doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mstsc

Answer (score 0):

Try this and put it is a batch file:

```
@echo off
title Connect to server . . . .
set /p SERVER=Please enter the server name: 
title Connecting to server %SERVER%
mstsc.exe /v: <Your server name:port>
```

Answer (score 0):

Input the following into a batch file.
Tested and it works for Windows 7

```
mstsc.exe /v:(IP-Address-of-Server)
```

E.g. `mstsc.exe /v:192.168.1.2`